# Understanding this object creation statement

Tags: perl, object

I'm not too familiar with Perl, but I am using it for a simple script I am going to write.  This script will interface with Qualys so while looking up information about the Qualys API I found this statement while looking through their sample code.  I have put it on Pastebin.com ([here](http://pastebin.com/VMg2dysJ)) so you don't have to download it to view it. If for some reason you do want to download it yourself, [here](https://community.qualys.com/community/developer) is a link to the page where I got it for those that want to be able to download the source (it's the "Get Map" one).

Anyways, here is the statement (line 261) that has me a little confused:

```
$request = new HTTP::Request GET => $url;
```

I'm confused about the `new` and `GET => $url` parts of the statement.

1. I think I mostly understand what's going on with the `new` part of the statement, but if someone could explain how the `HTTP::Request` works with creating a new `LWP::UserAgent` that would help clarify this line (I looked at LWP::UserAgent on CPAN, but the "KEY/DEFAULT" table they have under the `new` subroutine explanation made little sense to me).
2. I really have no idea what is happening in the `GET => $url` part of the statement.  My guess is that it is assigning a value in either `HTTP::Request` or `LWP::UserAgent` but I can't find any information to back  up that idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given line is equivalent to

```
$request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
```

which could also be written as

```
$request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $url);
```

The example used the indirect method syntax.

The connection between `HTTP::Request` and `LWP::UserAgent` is sketched in the [CPAN documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.03/lib/HTTP/Request.pm) as followes:

```
require HTTP::Request;
$request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.example.com/');

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$response = $ua->request($request);
```

So The `HTTP:.Request->new(...)` creates a new *request* which can be executed by a *user agent*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I never knew that you could call `new` from a module by putting it in front of the package.

Comment: You can do that with any class or object method. e.g. `request $ua $request;` could be used instead of `$ua->request($request)`. Most people only use it for `new` (`new Class @args`) because they like to prentend they're using C++ or Java, and for `print` (`print $fh $stuff`) for historical reasons. Assuming they use it at all.

Comment: And it's not recommended to use indirect method syntax at all, because it can lead to parsing ambiguities.